# Use "Define" variable from another php file

Tags: php

Hello i have a question!

**Main.php**

```
define("foo", "bar")
```

**Another.php**

```
require 'Main.php';

echo $foo; // prints empty string
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: That is not how a [`define`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) is used. Look at the link provided. If your error reporting is on, it should be showing an error.

Comment: @Script47 then how do i create a file full of defined variables and then link it to any file.

Comment: [Variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) !== [Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

Comment: It should be `echo foo`

Answer (score 0):

define is used for declaring a **constant** not a **variable**. You can get output with something like this

```
echo foo;
```

For declaring constants using upper case is best practice, like FOO, and you won't be able to change the value of it as it is constant. Try to learn about [variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) and [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) and how to declare it or use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) as following:

`define("CONSTANT", "Hello world");
 echo CONSTANT;`

So in your case use `echo foo;` instead of `echo $foo;`

Answer (score 0):

> Constant names do not need a leading dollar sign ($)

You  can get value without "$" just use a "name" of constant variable

**Your solution is**

```
<?php
    require 'Main.php';

    echo foo;
    ?>
```

another example

```
<?php

    define("MAXSIZE", 100);

    echo MAXSIZE;
    echo constant("MAXSIZE"); // same thing as the previous line

?>
```